# Can we axe the 'technique' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [technique](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) tag is overly broad, could apply to every craft we have, and doesn't tell us anything about what's physically needing to be done or which craft it's for, without the addition of another tag.

In short, it adds no real value to questions, gives no search benefits, and runs a bit counter to our other trend of not using such broad tags:

["Tools" tag is too broad - should it be removed/blacklisted?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/tools-tag-is-too-broad-should-it-be-removed-blacklisted)
[Is maintenance really tool-maintenance?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/is-maintenance-really-tool-maintenance)

Comment: I removed the last few last night as you clearly have seen. Do we need to delete it or something?

Comment: @Matt A tag with no questions is automatically deleted after 24 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It serves no useful purpose and should be removed

This tag is not a good fit in general but especially here at Arts & Crafts. Taking the current wiki excerpt (Which I put there and borrowed from a tag of the same name over at WW.SE)

> A process to achieve desired results.

That is what many people are going to be here for. They want to know how to do something. The tag does not narrow that sentiment or add to it. That is made very clear in questions that are "applicable" for this tag. It could be added to all of the those questions.

Like you say: Searching with it would accomplish nothing as users would be shown the many genres of A&C and that is not what they would be looking anyway. Just looking for [crocheting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crocheting) would be more effective by providing a *simple* way to get related content.

In [the Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) this concept is discussed and there are two criteria listed as reason for this tag not to exist.

**If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a meta-tag**

You cannot ask a question that is solely about technique. It has to be a technique related to *something*. More importantly no one can be a master of "technique".

**If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it's probably a meta-tag**

The techniques involved in one craft or art, while related to some similar arts and crafts, are generally completely unrelated and not applicable to most others.

The tag [technique](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) should just be removed from questions currently using. If we are correct then removing it should not cause the question any harm whatsoever and all the tags left will suit the question just fine.

Be aware of other edits to the question that might be helpful. Don't just do tag edits if there is other work to be done.

Comment: Classifying it as a meta tag makes perfect sense. Well argued.