# I don't think we need [practice]

Tags: discussion, tags

I have seen [practice](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) show up on a couple of questions now. I should think that it is a given that people are here to learn and practice. Comes part and parcel with the territory of SE and especially Arts & Crafts.SE

[Definitely feels like a meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that we don't want.

The tag can't work as the only tag on a question and the tag means different things to different crafts. The searching of the word practice should be enough.

I think this is an obvious candidate for outright removal. It's only on 2 questions currently so a couple of little bumps are not going to hurt anyone.

In the case of [practice](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice)( which seems similar to [technique](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) to me) this tag could easily be added to *many* questions. Does it add any value to them or make them easier to find? Perhaps. There likely isn't any harm in using them. If we are to keep practice it would be nice to get a good wiki and understanding of sample usage.

Answer (score 7):

I agree. [practice](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) isn't a necessary tag, as it's already part of the nature of many of those questions, and generally doesn't fit as you've said. Similarly, we wouldn't want "getting-started", "tutorial" or "basics" tags.

We already removed a somewhat similar tag:

[Can we axe the 'technique' tag?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/can-we-axe-the-technique-tag)

"Practice" can just be an alternative way to say "exercise technique", if that helps to illustrate why reasons for getting rid of technique work for [practice](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice), too.

Comment: _Practice_ will always be found in conjunction with another tag (e.g. _origami_ or _watercolor_ or _welding_ or whatever), so no real loss in axing it.

Comment: There are techniques related to practice, however... For example, gesture drawing is a form of figure drawing practice used by many artists as a warm up technique. Questions about *how to practice* for various mediums has merit.

Comment: @JohnCavan Gesture drawing is a specific technique/field warranting its own tag, which may be true of similar examples. I don't see anything wrong with asking about practice, but I'm not convinced we'd gain anything from having such a tag.

Comment: There are similar practice techniques across a wide variety of other mediums as well. The tag wasn't necessarily specifically bad, though the usage may have been, but I think that was a different problem. I'm not totally sold either way, but I think it may be wise to allow for more than a couple of hours for discussion as we're a low traffic site. :)

Comment: If I want to find all practice techniques related to watercolor then I could have potentially searched on [watercoloring] [practice] and narrowed the results. The advantage of tags is in being able to drill down without knowing about techniques like gesture drawing and so, then, if the tag has merit for that purpose, when applied correctly, then it probably should stick around.

Comment: @JohnCavan Pardon the pun, but where would we *draw the line* on what's practice, outside of the question itself saying "practice"?

Comment: I may have jumped the gun, I admit. With the similarities between [practice] and [technique], and a relatively high number of votes ([for us](http://data.stackexchange.com/craftsme/query/603308/average-score-of-answers-by-year-and-month)) in a short period of time, I didn't expect much else to come of this. I had just seen a few meta questions where nothing happened after 6+ months, I might have over-corrected here. I'm happy and willing to keep discussing it, or coming up with a new solution, though.

Comment: That's part of the discussion, if we're having it. The word has a few meanings, but I think I have provided some examples of appropriate context. Ultimately, I think my point is to consider slowing down a tad... A growing site needs meta engagement, so a quick response to this sort of question is probably to be avoided, it discourages engagement.

Comment: The other trick is to figure out how to increase the meta engagement. I'm used to getting notified, so I often forget to check in here. :)

Comment: As a side note to all of this, making the assumption that practice is linked to beginner techniques is incorrect. Professionals in all forms of arts practice continuously and extensively, this is how they become, and remain, professionals.

Answer (score 1):

If the tag is used correctly, as in *how to practice*, then it has merit. By that, I think when used to deal with questions related to techniques for practicing in certain mediums or art forms, then the use of the tag can be valuable in a drill down in a search. For example, if I want to find all of the question related to practice techniques for watercolor, without knowing their name, it would be handy to search on:

```
is:question [watercoloring] [practice]
```

So, I think the real issue isn't that the tag is without merit, it's that it's being misused.

---

**EDIT**

For example, which I previously mentioned, a question about how to gesture draw for the purpose of practicing figure drawing might want to tag [drawing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) and [practice](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) helping people to discover the context, they may not even know about gesture drawing in the first place. Drawing is especially interesting, there are quite a few different practicing techniques to help people learn and master.

Another possibility, from my favorite medium, is a question on how to practice watercolor techniques for gradient washes. There are approaches to doing this, some structured, some less so. You want to practice techniques like wet into wet before using it on your masterpiece.

In any event, I'm not glued to the term "practice" as such, but since the Meta post kind of called it out... Conceptually, anyways, having some means to bring concepts like this together does make some sense to me.

Comment: Tags are a delicate flower it seems. I have used that logic to try and save other tags and it really hasn't helped. We don't _need_ that tag and if someone wanted they could just add the word practice just as easily. Do you have some examples of how you would use the tag correctly? I think it would help your case if you show some examples where you think the tag works

Comment: Sorry, by that logic, why have tags at all? I can add the word "watercolor" too and search on that just as easily. There are ways to practice in just about any media or art form, being able to find those in context is just as useful. Technique, on the other hand, was pointless, almost every question is about technique.

Comment: Yes, you have a point. I am just very tired. [practice] does not work on its own is all. I would still like to see some examples of it being used properly in your answer.

Comment: So, would you apply it to every question about a technique that's used for practice? Or just questions explicitly asking how to use that technique for practice?

Comment: Side question: is practice the best name for this tag, if used as you've suggested? Does something like [how-to-practice] or [practice-technique] make the use case more clear?